# problemas com header em php

Tags: php, header

Olá, estou estudando php, e uma das tarefas é que preciso fazer uma autenticação para algumas páginas, estou usando $_SESSIONS para isso, e queria que caso os valores de $_SESSION['nome'] $_SESSION['senha'], fossem vazios, ser redirecionado para a página de login, porém não é isso que acontece, quando clico para abrir a página sem estar logado, ocorre o seguinte:

"Notice: Undefined index: nome in E:\xampp\htdocs\final\hardware.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: senha in E:\xampp\htdocs\final\hardware.php on line 4
falha na autenticação"

Alguém tem ideia do que eu possa fazer? Abaixo segue o código:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['nome']=$_POST['nome'];
$_SESSION['senha']=$_POST['senha'];

if ($_SESSION['nome']=="abc" && $_SESSION['senha']=="abc")
{
    include ("cabecalho.php");
    echo "teste";
    include ("rodape.php");
    echo  "</div> </body> </html>";
}

elseif($_SESSION['nome'] == " " || $_SESSION['senha'] == " ")

{
    header("Location:login.php");
}

else
{
    echo "falha na autenticação";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você abrir a página direto isso vai ocorrer porque o conteúdo da sessão "nome" e "senha" é carregado através de um conteúdo de um POST (que não ocorreu). Por isso que aparece o erro de "undefined index".

Uma das formas de evitar isso seria criar as sessões nome e senha e utilizar a função "isset" para verificar se o POST existe e atualizar o seu conteúdo. Seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['nome']= "";
$_SESSION['senha']= "";
if (isset($_POST['nome'])){
    $_SESSION['nome']=$_POST['nome'];
}
if (isset($_POST['senha'])){
    $_SESSION['senha']=$_POST['senha'];
}

if ($_SESSION['nome']=="abc" && $_SESSION['senha']=="abc")
{
    include ("cabecalho.php");
    echo "teste";
    include ("rodape.php");
    echo  "</div> </body> </html>";
}

elseif($_SESSION['nome'] == " " || $_SESSION['senha'] == " ")

{
    header("Location:login.php");
}

else
{
    echo "falha na autenticação";
}
?>
```